# Drupal Commerce: Alter 'Checkout' link in user menu

Tags: commerce

How do you hook into the 'checkout' link in the user menu?

If there is an item in the basket, want to be able to add a class to the 'checkout' link.

Ideally from the theme template and not hacking the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function in your custom module to return a bool for determining if there items in the basket/cart.

```
function items_on_cart(){
global $user;
$cart = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$line_items = count($cart->commerce_line_items) ? true : false;
return $line_items;
}
```

Then in your theme template do the following...

```
function YOURTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {

    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';
    $name_id = strtolower(strip_tags($element['#title']));  

    // add class to checkout link if basket active
    if ($name_id == 'checkout') {
        if (YOURMODULE_items_on_cart()) {
          $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `fn items_on_cart` means ?

Comment: Seems like copy paste from this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31178/commerce-is-there-something-in-the-basket

Comment: Answer has been edited.