# Commerce: is there something in the basket?

Tags: commerce

Is there a global variable of sorts that can be used as a bool to determine if something is in the basket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i use :)

```
function items_on_cart(){
  global $user;
  $cart = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
  $line_items = count($cart->commerce_line_items) ? true : false;
  return $line_items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Commerce Cart has the following function [`commerce_cart_order_session_exists()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_session_exists/7) which you could probably use to set a boolean value.

> Checks to see if any order ID or a specific order ID exists in the
>   session.

To answer your question directly though, there is no global variable to detect carts.

Comment: Thanks Chapabu, another good answer, just Marius pipped you to the post.