# Display number of pending messages and friend request on the user menu

Tags: routes, blocks, privatemsg, users

I'm using [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) & [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) and the built-in user menu as a sidebar block. What I want is to display the unread messages count and the pending friends requests beside the links "My messages" & "My friends".

Any ideas of how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Mock-up:

[image: User Menu Mock-up]

Comment: ate you using drupal 7 ?

Comment: Yes, I am on Drupal 7.17!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end @mohit_rocks answer was useful but didn't work at all. Here's my workaround (based in what I learned from [Drupal Commerce: Alter 'Checkout' link in user menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30614/drupal-commerce-alter-checkout-link-in-user-menu) & [You have x pending relationships block](http://drupal.org/node/387542) - note that I posted this answer on the second too):

**YOURCUSTOMMOD.module**

```
<?php function YOURCUSTOMMOD_unread_messages(){
global $user;
$unread_messages = privatemsg_unread_count($user);
return $unread_messages;
}

function YOURCUSTOMMOD_count_pending_relationships($account = NULL){
global $user;
$pending_relationships = user_relationships_load(array('requestee_id' => $user->uid, 'approved' => 0));
$count = 0;
if (is_array($pending_relationships) && !empty($pending_relationships)) {
    foreach($pending_relationships as $requester_uid => $relationship) {
      if($user->uid != $requester_uid) {
        $count++;
       }
    }
}
return $count;
} ?>
```

**template.php**

```
<?php function YOURTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
$sub_menu = '';
$count = '';
$name_id = strtolower(strip_tags($element['#title']));  

// add counters
if ($name_id == 'mis mensajes') {
    $count = sineditmod_unread_messages();
    $count = '('.l($count, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']).')';
}
if ($name_id == 'mis amigos') {
    $count = sineditmod_count_pending_relationships();
    $count = '('.l($count, 'relationships/received', $element['#localized_options']).')';
}
$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . '<span class="count green">' . $count . '</span>' . "</li>\n";
}?>
```

*Note*: **Remember to clean the cache!**

Answer (score 2):

This will return the unread private messages in Drupal 7.

```
<?php
global $user; privatemsg_unread_count($user);
?>
```

Refer [this](http://drupal.org/node/1682044) for more discussion

This will return pending relationship request for the loggedin user.

```
<?php
function _count_pending_relationships($account = NULL) {
  $counts = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (!$account || $account->uid == 0) {
    global $user;
    $account = $user;
  }

  if (!isset($counts[$account->uid])) {
    $count = 0;
    $pending_relationships = user_relationships_load(array('requestee_id' => $account->uid, 'approved' => 0), array('count' => TRUE));
    if (!empty($pending_relationships)) {
      foreach($pending_relationships as $requester_uid => $relationship) {
        if($account->uid != $requester_uid) {
          $count++;
        }
      }
    }
    $counts[$account->uid] = $count;
  }

  return $counts[$account->uid];
}
?>
```

Refer [this](http://drupal.org/node/387542) for detail discussion.

You can create a block and create respective links with the functions shown above.

Comment: Do you think I can hook the existent user menu block to use those function you provided? What should I modify? I'm a beginner about modifying Drupals Modules behaviors by hooking or preprocessing. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Just do one thing, create new simple block module and display all the data.